# Highchart multiple axes - How can I add different starting coordinates?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a three series high stock chart. In which, two series data starts 3 points after first series. The chart getting loaded correctly but when I try to adjust the preview range, the first series 3 points getting hidden.

Here is the JSFiddle which demonstrates the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ysaoLcqg/14/

If you zoom out with preview range and move the preview range to the right and then to the left, area shaded in pink color is not visible anymore.

Eg:-

```
series: [{
                name: "Min",
                data: [['05-Apr-2013',5],['05-May-2013',10],['05-Jun-2013',15],['05-Jul-2013',20]],
                draggableY: true,
                type:'spline',
                dragMinY: 0,
                minPointLength: 0
            },
            {
                name: "Max",
                data:  [['05-Apr-2013',45],['05-May-2013',60],['05-Jun-2013',75],['05-Jul-2013',80]],
                draggableY: true,                
                type:'spline',
                dragMinY: 0,
                minPointLength: 0
            },
            {
                type:'spline',
                name: "Normal",
                data:[['05-Jan-2013',25],['05-Feb-2013',35],['05-Mar-2013',45],['05-Apr-2013',25],['05-May-2013',30],['05-Jun-2013',45],['05-Jul-2013',50]]
            }]
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

This because base series for navigator is by default first series and it lacks first 3 points, so you are not able to set such range that will be outside. You can change that by setting `navigator: {baseSeries: 2}` because your longest series is third series (indexed from 0, so 2). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ysaoLcqg/15/